# How do I fix "TypeError: background is null"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to draw a background with the `<canvas>` tag and Javascript. However, I keep running into this error: `TypeError: background is null`

My canvas tagged is assigned to `bgCanvas`. Full script can be found here: https://codepen.io/loktar00/pen/uEJKl

HTML:

```
<canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var background = document.getElementById("bgCanvas"),
    bgCtx = background.getContext("2d"),
    width = window.innerWidth,
    height = document.body.offsetHeight;
```

I wish to use this script as a background for a website. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Going to your link, there appears to be no such error.

Comment: This is rather a duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)